# How to compute path to file in public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filepath, public

I created a folder called `Uploads` in my `public` folder.

I'd like to have people be able to click a link and download a file in that `Uploads` folder.

Here's my code:

```
<p>
  <b>Certifications</b>

  <%= link_to @tutor.tutor_degrees.first.name, # => "AS Level English"
      root_path + @tutor.tutor_degrees.first.certification_scan %>
</p>

http://localhost:3000/Screen%20shot%202013-02-04%20at%206.01.11%20PM.png
```

It's missing the `/uploads/` bit in the URL path.

If I add that string manually, I get a borked URL:

```
<p>
  <b>Certifications</b>
  <%= link_to @tutor.tutor_degrees.first.name,
      root_path + '/uploads/' + @tutor.tutor_degrees.first.certification_scan %>
</p>

http://uploads/Screen%20shot%202013-02-04%20at%206.01.11%20PM.png
```

Comment: Turns out I needed `root_url` not `root_path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<%= link_to @tutor.tutor_degrees.first.name, "http://#{request.host}/uploads/#{@tutor.tutor_degrees.first.certification_scan}" %>
```

must work :)